# Android Ble AdvertisingSet not sending scanResponse

Tags: java, android, bluetooth-lowenergy

it looks like advertisingSet does not send the scan response passed in parameter.
Does anyone know what i'm doing wrong here ?

AdvertisingSet :

```
AdvertisingSetParameters parameters = (new AdvertisingSetParameters.Builder())
                .setConnectable(false)
                .setLegacyMode(true)
                .setInterval(AdvertisingSetParameters.INTERVAL_HIGH)
                .setTxPowerLevel(AdvertisingSetParameters.TX_POWER_MEDIUM)
                .build();

byte[] packet = "hello".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);


AdvertiseData data = new AdvertiseData.Builder()
        .setIncludeDeviceName( true )
        .setIncludeTxPowerLevel(false)
        .addServiceUuid(serviceId)
        .build();

AdvertiseData response = new AdvertiseData.Builder()
        .setIncludeDeviceName( false )
        .setIncludeTxPowerLevel(false)
        .addServiceUuid(serviceId)
        .addServiceData(serviceId, packet )
        .build();
        

advertiser.startAdvertisingSet(parameters, data, response, null, null,callback);
```

Scanner :

```
List<ScanFilter> filters = new ArrayList<>();
ScanFilter filter = new ScanFilter.Builder()
        .setServiceUuid(serviceId)
        .build();
filters.add( filter );

// Setting scanning mode to low latency
ScanSettings scanSettings = new ScanSettings.Builder()
        .setScanMode( ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_LOW_LATENCY )
        .build();



bluetoothLeScanner.startScan(filters, scanSettings,
        new ScanCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onScanResult(int callbackType, ScanResult result) {
                super.onScanResult(callbackType, result);
                Log.d(TAG, scanResult.toString());

            }

            @Override
            public void onBatchScanResults(List<ScanResult> results) {
                super.onBatchScanResults(results);
            }

            @Override
            public void onScanFailed(int errorCode) {
                super.onScanFailed(errorCode);
                Log.e(TAG, "onScanFailed: " + errorCode);
            }
        });
```

this is what is given by the scaner callback, as you can see, the scanResponse has not been found as the serviceData is empty. What am i missing ?

```
ScanResult{device=6F:26:02:1A:91:E7,
 scanRecord=ScanRecord [mAdvertiseFlags=-1,
 mServiceUuids=[0000950d-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb],
 mManufacturerSpecificData={},
 mServiceData={},
 mTxPowerLevel=-2147483648,
 mDeviceName=1RLjXZvX/Default user],
 rssi=-62,
 timestampNanos=11220453733034,
 eventType=16,
 primaryPhy=1,
 secondaryPhy=0,
 advertisingSid=255,
 txPower=127,
 periodicAdvertisingInterval=0}
```

Answer (score -1):

Add setScannable(true) to the advertisingSetParameters. Thats what I did.

```
   AdvertisingSetParameters.Builder advertisingSetParametersBuilder = (new AdvertisingSetParameters.Builder())
                .setConnectable(false)
                .setScannable(true)
                .setInterval(AdvertisingSetParameters.INTERVAL_MIN)
                .setTxPowerLevel(AdvertisingSetParameters.TX_POWER_MIN);
```

Comment: Hello, Tony please add some descriptions, of why you have taken these actions

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).